# Qt. Начало работы

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Установил Qt Creator версии 4.8.2. Хочу создать проект приложения с интерфейсом, но комплекты нельзя выбрать. Есть только Desktop в настройках. Что я не так делаю? Как добавить комплекты в проект? Вот скриншот Возможно вопрос глупый, но я уже 10 минут не могу понять в чем дело.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю скриншот Desktop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот профили Qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите что в комплекте Desktop

Comment: На форме же есть ссылочка на настройки с добавлением коплекта, там и настраивайте

Comment: Дело раскрыто - _Профиль Qt : Отсутствует_

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb И как его добавить?

Comment: А у вас установлен Qt? Для ясности: Qt - это, грубо говоря, библиотека, которая позволяет создавать окошки. Весит 2-3 гига. Qt Creator - IDE, которая позволяет редактировать код. Весит 100-200 метров

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Я скачивал Qt отсюда. https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5 Qt Creator одна из папок которые распаковались при установке, так что думаю, что все установлено.

Comment: Окей, покажите вкладку "Профили Qt"

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb добавил скрин вкладки

Comment: Ну да, у вас нет профилей Qt. Нажмите Комплекты->Профили Qt->Добавить. Укажите путь к qmake.exe, который лежит гдето внутри Qt. Профиль добавится. Потом для комплекта Desktop ваберите этот профиль. Если вдруг окажется что qmake.exe нигде нет, значит Qt вы все-же не посавили.